# How To Open Chrome Browser window with a specific URL with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, siebel

How To Open Chrome Browser window with a specific URL with JavaScript in Internet Explorer 8?

Any Suggestions or Ideas?

Comment: Do you know if the user has Google Chrome installed?

Comment: yes i do know that the user will have Chrome

Comment: You can't open a windows program from a browser. That would be a security gap.

Comment: I know it is possible with Microsoft Edge, but I'm also seeking a solution for Chrome. It can be accomplished with Edge like this: `window.open("microsoft-edge:"+ window.location.href)`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var openUrl = window.open('url');
```

It will use the default browser to open the specified url.

Comment: I need to open Chrome Specifically